# Wagtail, only administrator / superuser can log into admin

Tags: permissions, wagtail

I am getting started with Wagtail but I only seem to be able to log in users who have "administrator" role set (I tried setting is_staff via the normal Django admin, but that didn't work).

I saw this post which suggests that groups should have a "Can access wagtail admin" permission, but this is not displayed on either the group or user pages in the Wagtail admin.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wagtail/DAHGX97kBiE

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? 
(Wagtail 1.10, Django 1.11)

Comment: The checkbox should be under "Other Permissions" when you go to Settings -> Groups and edit a group - are you sure it's not there? http://files.zxdemo.org/extra/forum/wagtail-admin-permission.png

Comment: Its not there. I did manage to empty the database tables so I needed to add the root document to get it started. Have I managed to delete a permission entry from the database maybe?

Comment: Yes, that would explain it - it's an entry in the `auth_permissions` table. Unfortunately there's no way of knowing what other broken behaviour will arise as a result of wiping the database contents... I'd strongly recommend deleting and rebuilding the database from scratch with `./manage.py migrate` (making a dump of any non-Wagtail tables you want to keep first, of course).

Comment: Yes, it looks like that is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is about a year and a half old, but here's the answer I've come up with for Wagtail 2.1 (Running Django 2.06)

In your group permission settings (Log into /admin/, go to Settings > Groups) you can edit the groups (or add a new one).

When you're setting the permissions of a group, select the `Can access Wagtail admin` option. It looks like this:
[image]

Save the groups permissions, and your users will now be able to log into the CMS admin. The user doesn't need to be `is_staff` or `is_superuser`, just a regular user will work. But the user needs to be `Active` inside Wagtail. Open Settings > Users, select your user you want to edit, and make sure the user checkbox is `Active`.

Wagtail takes care of pretty much all of this for you. If this doesn't work on an older version of Wagtail, try upgrading your Wagtail version.